# Given coordinates of hypotenuse, how can I calculate coordinates of other vertex?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have the Cartesian coordinates of the hypotenuse 'corners' in a right angle triangle. I also have the length of the sides of the triangle. What is the method of determining the coordinates of the third vertex where the opposite & adjacent sides meet.

Thanks, Kevin.

Comment: @maud - I spent 6 hours yesterday on this, going off in the wrong direction as it turns out. Sleeping on it brought no inspiration so I asked the question here. I can take a picture of increasingly muddled scribblings for your review, but a) It wouldn't improve the question, b) the FAQ doesn't indicate its necessary and c) I saw no precedent for this when I searched other related questions.

Comment: Kevin: mentioning something along the lines of "I tried method X and it went to crap" wouldn't have hurt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two points $A=(a,b)$ and $B=(c,d)$ and want a point $P$
at given distances from $A$ and $B$, say $l$ and $m$. Then $|PA|^2=l^2$
and $|PB|^2=m^2$ that is
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=l^2\qquad\qquad(1)$$
and
$$(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2=m^2.\qquad\qquad(2)$$
Subtracting (2) from (1) gives a linear equation. Use this to eliminate
one variable from (1). This yields a quadratic equation in the other variable.
Solving this will give the two possible positions for $P$.

Comment: Geometrically, subtracting equation 2 from equation 1 is equivalent to finding the radical line (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalLine.html ) of the two circles represented by the two equations.

Answer (score 2):

While I'd use the same algebra as [Robin Chapman's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5129/given-coordinates-of-hypotenuse-how-can-i-calculate-coordinates-of-other-vertex/5130#5130), my first thought on this problem yields a third circle equation.  The circumcenter of a right triangle is at the midpoint of its hypotenuse.  Given the endpoints of the hypotenuse, $A=(a,b)$ and $B=(c,d)$, and letting $h$ be the length of the hypotenuse, the circumcircle has equation
$$\left(x-\frac{a+c}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{b+d}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)^2.$$
This may look a bit intimidating in symbols, but isn't really any different to work with for solving than the other two circles.  I don't know that this offers any advantages, though.

Comment: This is related to the geometric fact that an angle inscribed in a semicircle is a right angle. I suppose there are cases where the algebra with this approach is easier than Robin's, and conversely.

Comment: @J.M.: This fact can also be thought of as the locus of vertices of right angles where the sides of the angles pass through two given points is a circle.  It is interesting to consider this locus for angles of other measures.  I doubt the algebra could be much different with this equation than either of Robin's--in either case, the simplest method of solution is probably to expand both circle equations, subtract to get the radical line, and substitute back into one circle to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB$ the hypotenuse, let vector $\vec c=\overrightarrow{OB}-\overrightarrow{OA}$, its length $c$, the right angle at $C$, $DC=h$ the height of the triangle, $a$ and $b$ the given length of the legs, $q$ length of $AD$ as usual.  Define $J\colon R^2\rightarrow R^2$, $(v_1,v_2)\mapsto (-v_2,v_1)$ the rotation by 90 degree.

We know by Euclid that $q=b^2/c$ and elementarily that $ab=ch$, so $h=ab/c$. Then $\vec c/c$ is the unit vector of $c$, thus one solution is
$$\overrightarrow{OC}=\overrightarrow{OA}+\frac{b^2}{c}\frac{\vec c}{c}+\frac{ab}{c}J\Bigl(\frac{\vec c}{c}\Bigr)=\overrightarrow{OA}+\frac{b}{c^2}\bigl(b\vec c+ aJ(\vec c)\big).$$
Can you find the second solution?

Moral: Avoid coordinates!

Michael