# Geometry, Creating rectangle given 2 diagonal points.

Tags: geometry

ok so i've encountered some post about it but i just cant understand why it works..

Given 2 opposite points of Rectangle (X1,Y1) , (X3,Y3)
Need to find the other 2 points.

so some one in this [Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506785/given-two-diagonally-opposite-points-on-a-square-how-to-calculate-the-other-two) offered this as an answer:

```
  x1 = ?  ;  y1 = ? ;    // First diagonal point
  x2 = ?  ;  y2 = ? ;    // Second diagonal point

  xc = (x1 + x2)/2  ;  yc = (y1 + y2)/2  ;    // Center point
  xd = (x1 - x2)/2  ;  yd = (y1 - y2)/2  ;    // Half-diagonal

  x3 = xc - yd  ;  y3 = yc + xd;    // Third corner
  x4 = xc + yd  ;  y4 = yc - xd;    // Fourth corner
```

i just cant understand why it works, help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you've stated has no unique solution. See [image: this picture of three different rectangles with the same diagonal points.]

The code's author has created a rectangle that's vertically aligned and has those two corners. The idea is to find the center (whose $x$-coord is the average of the  two corners' $x$-coords, and similarly for $y$), and then create a ray from the center to one of the known corners (that's what's labeled "Half-diagonal". $x_d$ is the $x$ distance from the center point to the first corner; thus taking $x_c \pm x_d$, you get the x-coordinates of the two corners; the same argument goes for $y$.

There's a much simpler solution: GIven $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$, the four corners of an axis-aligned rectangle are
$$
(x_1, y_1), (x_1, y_2), (x_2, y_2), (x_2, y_1).
$$

Comment: well that what i used for vertically aligned rectange but i was wondering what heppens if it rotates..

Comment: The code you've given will always give an axis-aligned rectangle for the two input points. So will my alternative. If you allow the possibility that the output might not be axis-aligned, then there is no unique solution, as my figure shows. So the problem of finding  THE rectangle with the given two corners is unsolvable.  In my example with the blue dots as the corners, which of the three colored rectangles is THE right answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the circle that has the given two points as endpoints of a diameter; and then if you choose any two other diametrically opposite points on that circle, the four points on the circle are the corners of a rectangle of the desired type.