# Calculate opposite points in Square from diagonal.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I see the following solution from another link, but can't get my head around it as to why this works.

Especially , with square sides not parallel to x/y axis. Like why subtracting/adding half the diagonal length always gives correct third and fourth points.

Can someone please explain.

Link:
[Given two diagonally opposite points on a square, how to calculate the other two points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506785/given-two-diagonally-opposite-points-on-a-square-how-to-calculate-the-other-two)

```
  x1 = ?  ;  y1 = ? ;    // First diagonal point
  x2 = ?  ;  y2 = ? ;    // Second diagonal point

  xc = (x1 + x2)/2  ;  yc = (y1 + y2)/2  ;    // Center point
  xd = (x1 - x2)/2  ;  yd = (y1 - y2)/2  ;    // Half-diagonal

  x3 = xc - yd  ;  y3 = yc + xd;    // Third corner
  x4 = xc + yd  ;  y4 = yc - xd;    // Fourth corner
```

Comment: Perhaps it may help you to recall that the diagonals of a square are perpendicular.  How do the slopes of perpendicular lines compare?

Comment: Yes , with slopes(m) and m1.m2=-1 .  We do get the other points by getting the equations of the other lines and point at the distance from that point. But that's too many steps. Somehow the above equations considers everything. I think I am missing some observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have two points: $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$. The first step is to find midpoint $M(x_c,y_c)$. This is straightforward: $x_c=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, y_c=\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}$

The next step is to move the origin to point $M$. Our points $A$ and $B$ will have new coordinates: $A'(x_1-x_c,y_1-y_c)$ and $B'(x_2-x_c,y_2-y_c)$.

Finally, we rotate $A'B'$ about the origin $90$ degrees to get the other two vertices. The rotated points will be $A''(y_c-y_1, x_1-x_c)$ and $B''(y_c-y_2, x_2-x_c)$. Moving the origin back to the original location will give us coordinates of the vertices: $C(y_c-y_1+x_c, x_1-x_c+y_c)$ and $D(y_c-y_2+x_c, x_2-x_c+y_c)$. We don't really need to calculate half-diagonal but it's easy to see that $y_c-y_1=-y_d$ and so forth.