# Finding the other two vertices of a square, given opposite vertices $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$

Tags: geometry

I came across the following sentence;

Let (a,b) and (c,d) be two
opposite vertices of a square, so that the other two vertices are
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{a - b+c+d}{2}, \frac{a+b - c+d}{2}\right)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{a + b+c-d}{2}, \frac{-a+b + c+d}{2}\right)
\end{equation}

While this can be verified using the distance formula and the dot product (to show that the sides are perpendicular), I was wondering if there was a natural way to motivate this.

Comment: Maybe the answers here provide some motivation:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506785/given-two-diagonally-opposite-points-on-a-square-how-to-calculate-the-other-two?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translate the coordinate system so that the midpoint $(\frac{a+c}{2}, \frac{b+d}{2})$ maps to the origin.  Then the vertices $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$ become $(a - \frac{a+c}{2}, b - \frac{b+d}{2}) = (\frac{a-c}{2}, \frac{b-d}{2}),$ and the other is simply the negative of this.  Rotating them by $90^\circ$ gives
$$\pm \left(\frac{d-b}{2}, \frac{a-c}{2}\right),$$ and then undoing the translation gives the claimed result.