# Given two diagonally opposite points on a square, how to calculate the other two points of the square

Tags: geometry

**My backgroud**: I'm a high school student. I just learned about the cartesian and polar coordinate systems. And learned to calculate the distance of two points on a cartesian plane.

#### The question was:

Two diagonally opposite points of a square is given.
A(6,3) and C(-2,-3)
Now, find the coordinates of point B and D (Other 2 points of a square basically)

#### What I tried:

At first, I assumed the middle point of AC as P(x,y); then I calculated the length of AC.
AC = 10 units;
AP = 5 units;
The coordinate of P is, P(2,0)
Now again I assumed B as B($\alpha, \beta$) and D as D(a, b)
But after that I'm stuck.
Then I tried to form different equations but didn't
get to anywhere.

Like:
$$AB=\sqrt{(6-\alpha)^{2}+(3-\beta)^{2}}{}$$
$$BC = \sqrt{(2+\alpha)^{2}+(2+\beta)^{2}}{}$$
$$PB = \sqrt{(2-\alpha)^{2}+\beta^{2}}{} = 5$$
$$PD = \sqrt{(2-a)^{2}+b^{2}}{} = 5$$
.....
I don't know anymore.
Please help me out.

Comment: I think [Michael Hoppe's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506807/472818) is best.